# help using cylindrical coordinates to set up this integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, euclidean-geometry

[image]

I know how to set up the z boundaries, and that the integral should be in order of $dzdrd\theta$, but I'm not sure how to get the radius. I know I could add $x^2 + y^2$ to both sides and turn that into$ r^2$ but I'm not sure what to do with the z. Can someone help give me insight on this and show me how its supposed to be set up? I read the examples in the book but they aren't clear on how to translate the paraboloid to boundaries.

Comment: So the first octant is the positive $xy$-plane, which is one fourth of the unit circle, which means that $\theta$ ranges from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: $r$ would run from $0$ to $2$

Comment: can you show me how r would run from 0 to 2?

Comment: Making the substitution $x^2+y^2=r^2$ we have $z=4-r^2$, since $z=0$ when $r=2$ we know that this must be the bounds for $r$

Comment: We also know the lower bound for $z$ must be $0$ since our solid is confined to the first octant where $z$ does not become negative

Comment: so when finding the r boundaries you are simply supposed to solve the equation for r where z = 0.

Comment: Not always, we used that as a limiting case for our purposes because we were given $z$ and its relationship to $x$ and $y$ which we used to convert to polar coordinates to solve for $r$

Comment: thanks this type of problem was on my quiz today :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_{0}^{ \frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{4-r^{2}}(r \cos \theta + r \sin \theta +z) r\,dz\,dr\,d\theta$.

Comment: Typo: you have $dt$ instead of $dr$

Comment: Thanks for the edit!

Comment: You're welcome :)